# Create a UI package with Emotion and consume it with Next.js application

Tags: reactjs, package, emotion

**Problem:**

We've built a UI package using **React**, **Emotion**, and **Vite**. We're consuming it in a Next.js app.

But when we import a component, we get the following `ServerError` -

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'registered')
```

Seems like the cache object is `null` on the server.
Even when adding `<CacheProvider>` to the Next.js app, we still get the same error.

**Extra information:**

Here's how our `vite.config.js` loos like -

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

import packageJson from './package.json';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
      babel: {
        plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
      },
    }),
  ],
  esbuild: {
    jsxInject: "import React from 'react'",
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'lib',
    lib: {
      entry: './src/index',
      formats: ['esm'],
      fileName: (format) => `ui.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // Externalize dependencies that shouldn't be bundled into library
      external: [...Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies)],
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue while working with Rollup, but I managed to resolve it by configuring Rollup in the following way:

```
plugins: [
  nodeResolve({
     // browser: true, --> disabled here
     extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  }),
]
```

You can try to custom your `rollupOptions` like above. Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with the same setup. Fixed it by adding `ssr: { noExternal: true }` and `build: { ssr: true }` to the vite config.

```
export default defineConfig({
  ssr: { noExternal: true },
  build: {
    ssr: true,
    minify: false,
    sourcemap: true,
    reportCompressedSize: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
      Types: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/types'),
      Utils: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/utils'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [react(), dts()],
});
```